# Directional Tooltip hiding

Tags: css, tooltip, z-index

How to make the tool-tip visible fully which is hiding back to table header.I tried increasing the z-index value and position but it doesn't works.i have attached my css code.

This is my css file:

```
    /* Base styles for the element that has a tooltip */
    [data-tooltip],
    .tooltip {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    }

    /* Base styles for the entire tooltip */
    [data-tooltip]:before,
    [data-tooltip]:after,
    .tooltip:before,
    .tooltip:after {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 
    opacity 0.2s ease-in-out,
    visibility 0.2s ease-in-out,
    -webkit-transform 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
    -moz-transition:    
    opacity 0.2s ease-in-out,
    visibility 0.2s ease-in-out,
    -moz-transform 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
    transition:         
    opacity 0.2s ease-in-out,
    visibility 0.2s ease-in-out,
    transform 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform:    translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform:         translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    pointer-events: none;
    }

    /* Show the entire tooltip on hover and focus */
    [data-tooltip]:hover:before,
    [data-tooltip]:hover:after,
    [data-tooltip]:focus:before,
    [data-tooltip]:focus:after,
    .tooltip:hover:before,
    .tooltip:hover:after,
    .tooltip:focus:before,
    .tooltip:focus:after {
    visibility: visible;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
    }

    /* Base styles for the tooltip's directional arrow */
    .tooltip:before,
    [data-tooltip]:before {

    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    z-index: 1001;
    border: 6px solid transparent;
    background: transparent;
    content: "";

    }

    /* Base styles for the tooltip's content area */
    .tooltip:after,
    [data-tooltip]:after {
    z-index: 1000;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #FFF;

    border:solid 1px #10427d;
    color: #000;
    content: attr(data-tooltip);
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height: 1.2;
    }

    /* Directions */

    /* Top (default) */
    [data-tooltip]:before,
    [data-tooltip]:after,
    .tooltip:before,
    .tooltip:after,
    .tooltip-top:before,
    .tooltip-top:after {
    bottom: 200%;
    left: 50%;
    }

    [data-tooltip]:before,
    .tooltip:before,
    .tooltip-top:before {
    margin-left: -6px;
    margin-bottom: -12px;
    border-top-color: #000;
    border-top-color: rgba(16, 66, 125, 1.0);
    }

    /* Horizontally align top/bottom tooltips */
    [data-tooltip]:after,
    .tooltip:after,
    .tooltip-top:after {
    margin-left: -80px;
    }

    [data-tooltip]:hover:before,
    [data-tooltip]:hover:after,
    [data-tooltip]:focus:before,
    [data-tooltip]:focus:after,
    .tooltip:hover:before,
    .tooltip:hover:after,
    .tooltip:focus:before,
    .tooltip:focus:after,
    .tooltip-top:hover:before,
    .tooltip-top:hover:after,
    .tooltip-top:focus:before,
    .tooltip-top:focus:after {
    /*background-color: white;*/
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-12px);
    -moz-transform:    translateY(-12px);
    transform:         translateY(-12px); 
    }

    /* Top Left */
    .tooltip-top-left:before,
    .tooltip-top-left:after {
    left: 0;
    }

    .tooltip-top-left:before {
    margin-left: 3px;
    }

    .tooltip-top-left:after {
    margin-left: 0;
    }

    /* Left */
    .tooltip-left:before,
    .tooltip-left:after {
    right: 107%;
    bottom: 50%;
    left: auto;
    }

    .tooltip-left:before {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: -12px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-top-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: #000;
    border-left-color: rgba(16, 66, 125, 1.0);
    }

    .tooltip-left:hover:before,
    .tooltip-left:hover:after,
    .tooltip-left:focus:before,
    .tooltip-left:focus:after {
    /*background-color: white;*/
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-12px);
    -moz-transform:    translateX(-12px);
    transform:         translateX(-12px); 
    }

    /* Bottom */
    .tooltip-bottom:before,
    .tooltip-bottom:after {
    top: 110%;
    bottom: auto;
    left: 50%;
    }

    .tooltip-bottom:before {
    margin-top: -12px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-top-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color: #000;
    border-bottom-color: rgba(16, 66, 125, 1.0);
    }

    .tooltip-bottom:hover:before,
    .tooltip-bottom:hover:after,
    .tooltip-bottom:focus:before,
    .tooltip-bottom:focus:after {
    /*background-color: white;*/
    -webkit-transform: translateY(12px);
    -moz-transform:    translateY(12px);
    transform:         translateY(12px); 
    }

    /* Right */
    .tooltip-right:before,
    .tooltip-right:after,
    .tooltip-right-top:before,
    .tooltip-right-top:after {
    bottom: 50%;
    left: 107%
    }

    .tooltip-right:before,
    .tooltip-right-top:before {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: -12px;
    border-top-color: transparent;
    border-right-color: #000;
    border-right-color: rgba(16, 66, 125, 1.0);
    }

    .tooltip-right:hover:before,
    .tooltip-right:hover:after,
    .tooltip-right:focus:before,
    .tooltip-right:focus:after,
    .tooltip-right-top:hover:before,
    .tooltip-right-top:hover:after,
    .tooltip-right-top:focus:before,
    .tooltip-right-top:focus:after {
    /*background-color: white;*/
    -webkit-transform: translateX(12px);
    -moz-transform:    translateX(12px);
    transform:         translateX(12px); 
    }

    /* Move directional arrows down a bit for left/right tooltips */
    .tooltip-left:before,
    .tooltip-right:before,
    .tooltip-right-top:before {
    /*top: -5px;*/
    }

    /* Vertically center tooltip content for left/right tooltips */
    .tooltip-left:after,
    .tooltip-right:after,
    .tooltip-right-top:after {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: -16px;
    }

    /* Right Top */
    .tooltip-right-top:after {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    bottom: -12px;
    }
```

rhtml:

```
<thead>
      <tr style="height:60px;">
        <th width="15%">
          <span class='tooltip-right' data-tooltip ="aaaaa" >
            <%= link_to_remote("Name",:url => {:controller => "ww", :action => "dd"}) %>
          </span>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `position: absolute` to the tooltip here, and apply `position: relative` to the `thead`.

Will bring out the tooltip on top.

Comment: that works great. but images on that page are static.                                   <td class="content_text1"> abc &nbsp;<span class='tooltip-right' data-tooltip ="abc"><img src="abc.png" border="0"></span></td>  -- where im using tooltip for the images.if i apply these positions images are static

Comment: You can apply `position: absolute` to the images as well. They will align with respect to the tooltips. Give the images a higher `z-index` for them to be shown on top of the tooltip.